# boost asio TCP server must bind to an IP address?

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, boost-asio

I am not sure whether I am using BOOST ASIO properly, my code is as follows,

```
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_);
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(std::string("127.0.0.1"), port);
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = *resolver.resolve(query);
  acceptor_.open(endpoint.protocol());
```

It binds to 127.0.0.1. When a client is connecting externally, the client is using the IP address 192.168.0.107 or something similar. The server implemented by BOOST ASIO just simply refuses the client connection.

So is there a way to deal with this? I think for apache2, the apache2 is not required to bind to a specific IP, any client requests from any server interface (provided there are multiple interfaces) can connect to apache2.

Is there a way to solve it? Or there's no way and I have to fix the server external IP?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bind to `0.0.0.0`. That's the "wildcard" that listens on all interfaces for any incoming connection.

If you bind to `127.0.0.1`, your server will only accept incoming connections over the loopback, which won't let you client connect (since your client isn't using the loopback).

Answer (score 5):

You can create a endpoint to listen on any IP like this:

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint ep(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), listen_port );
```